# Change background item of listview in Android

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-styles

I made a custom style for my listview. The problem is when i try to touch the item of listview. The row selected not change the background. If I set this property in my listview:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

The background of my item listview change, but I can't see the texview inside of the item listview.
May be I have to handler if the item is selected or not, but i don't know how to do it. Could you help me please?

This is my .xml when I have my listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_todos_los_complejos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:listSelector="#37474f"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_informacion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="BUTTON 1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_turno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="BUTTON 2"/>





    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is the listview format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/style_listview"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nombre_fila"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/id_fila"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the style of the listview is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3b464b" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4b5960"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

On touch the listiview item, only have to change the background color of the item. Thanks!

Comment: Please help me! :(